# Report Calendar-like with SQL and Excel

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008

I am about to create report which should look like as follows:

[image]

Is it possible to produce report like this with SQL and represent it in Excel? I am curious whether I am able to create something like this with these tools or not. I am out of ideas. Could you please point me to some direction? I am interested in conceptual solution.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use SSRS -

http://msdyn.blogspot.ie/2013/07/create-calendar-style-reports-in-sql.html

Comment: Yep, I found that one. It's my backup solution plan.